# Changing assets location in entries after moving them to a different volume

Tags: assets

I've moved all the assets from a local volume to a DigitalOcean space (S3 compatible) and all new entries are using that volume. I've updated all assets fields to use that new location.

My problem is that all the old entries, previous to this change, are still referencing the local volume, even though the same assets are already in the cloud storage.

Is there a way to force Craft to update all assets entries to the new location? When looking at the database, all the older assets are associated with the local volume. I've tried reindexing everything but that didn't solve it. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Thank you.

Comment: If string replacement will fix it, you could try using the Find and Replace utility in the admin panel.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that already but searching for the url string gives back 0 results :/

Comment: Are you using any cache tags or something that would make the templates hold onto the old URLs? If you resave an old entry in question, does it update?

Comment: Not using any cache but yes, when I update the entry it changes the assets url, but only if I double click the asset and hit save.

Comment: If you referred to these images using its absolute path, search replace should do it. But moving forward refer to the step 7 of [this post](https://nystudio107.com/blog/using-aws-s3-buckets-cloudfront-distribution-with-craft-cms#step-7-configure-your-asset-volumes-in-craft-cms) you shall never have this problem again.

Comment: @Leoncio thank you for your input. I'll keep that in mind.